# is it just the battery

Tags: battery

So last night my car wouldn't start . Everything in the car worked like the lights and radio but it just wouldn't start . I had my friend give me a jump and it started up no problem . So is this just a battery problem ..? Also I've been started three times today and nothing seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find any corrosion around the battery terminals, take the battery down to the parts store and have them load test it. That will tell you if it's just the battery. It could be the battery has a "surface charge" which will give it enough juice to start it a few times, but on the off chance you need to crank it over a little bit more, it will die. This is usually caused by a weak cell inside the battery. If there is corrosion around the terminals, ensure you get that cleaned up to allow for proper charging, with or without a new battery.